# Use Jenkins pipeline File parameter on Docker agent

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to parametrize a Jenkins pipeline with a File type parameter to be used on a docker based agent.

Added **a_file** parameter, the environment variable is available while executing, but not the file.

**Is there any specific steps or way to use file parameters on the Docker-based agent?**

An excerpt of the pipeline:

```
pipeline {
   agent { label 'master' }

   stages {
        stage('Use File parameter') {
            agent { 
                docker { 
                    image 'node:10'
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'env'
                sh 'ls ${a_file}'
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be a known limitation of default File parameters (https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-29289, https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-27413).

The alternative solution is to use Stashed File or base64 File parameter types from [File Parameters](https://plugins.jenkins.io/file-parameters/) plugin.